# emails fetched from imaplib have no newlines

Tags: python, django

I'm using following function to fetch mails in my django app:

```
def landing_page(request):
    mail.select('inbox')
    result, data = mail.uid('search', None, "ALL")
    i = len(data[0].split())
    for x in range(i, i-10, -1):
        status, data = mail.fetch(x, '(RFC822)')
        email_msg = email.message_from_string(data[0][1])
        if email_msg.is_multipart():
            for part in email_msg.walk():
                if part.get_content_type() == "text/plain":
                    body = part.get_payload(decode=True).decode("quoted-printable")

        else:
            body = email_msg.get_payload(decode=True).decode("quoted-printable")

        if body is None :
            body = "None"

        rec = MailTable(mid = x, subject = email_msg['subject'], sender = email_msg['from'], mail=body.decode('utf-8', 'ignore'))
        rec.save()
    return render(request, "landing_page.html", {})
```

What I get as result is this :

```
Hi Mayur,I scored 93 percentile in GRE and 95 percentile in high school. I applied for MBA for Harvard University and got selected!. Looking forward for a great career.!Your Sincerely,Cristo
```

What I want is this :

```
Hi Mayur,
  I scored 93 percentile in GRE and 95 percentile in high school.
I applied for MBA for Harvard University and got selected!. Looking forward for a great career.!
Your Sincerely,
Cristo
```

EDIT:

I'm passing the body as context and then displaying in html like :

```
<div class="bottom-box" id = "body-mail">
    {{ body_ }}
</div>
```

Comment: Is your output html or a string? In html, all whitespace will be displayed as a single space.

Comment: It's a string. I tried using jQuery $(document).ready for setting the .html of the ID but it fails since there are no '\'  in the end

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that your problem is not newlines, but breaks. Try:

```
body = body.replace('\n', '<br />\n')
```

Comment: now the result is `Hi Mayur, <br /> I scored 93 percentile in GRE and 95 percentile in high school. I applied <br /> for MBA for Harvard University and got selected!. Looking forward for a <br /> great career.! <br /> Your Sincerely, <br /> Cristo <br /> `

Comment: @cwallenpoole this won't work because Django will escape the tags before rendering.

Answer (score 2):

New lines are just concatenated to a single space in HTML. You can use the [`linebreaks`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaks) template filter to convert them into paragraphs:

```
<div class="bottom-box" id = "body-mail">
    {{ body_|linebreaks }}
</div>
```

There is also `linebreaksbr` which adds `<br>` tags instead of `<p>` tags.